# What do I type in a terminal to understand what commands mean?

Tags: command-line, documentation

Is there a shortcut key to list what each Help command in the Gnome Terminal means? I got it to list by accident but didn't know the key switch to slow down the list, I am guessing these are DOS?

Comment: I didn't really get the question. Do you want to know how to get info and help about each command?

Answer (score 5):

#### What Exactly Are Commands?

A command can be one of four different things:

1. An executable program like all those files in `/usr/bin`.
2. A command built into the shell itself.
3. A shell function.
4. An alias.

#### Identifying Commands

Usually use type to know what a command type is. for example:

```
$ type cd
cd is a shell builtin
```

Then this shows that `cd` command is a builtin command.

#### Getting help about commands:

- `help`: Get help for shell builtins
- `--help` – Display usage information
- `man` – Display a program's manual page
- `info` – Display a program's info entry
- `README` And other program documentation files

---

**`help`: Get Help For Shell Builtins**

use `help` for every shell builtin command. try this for example: `help cd`

---

**`--help` – Display Usage Information**

Many executable programs support a `--help` option that displays a description of the command's supported syntax and options. For example `mkdir --help`

---

**man – Display A Program's Manual Page**

Most executable programs intended for command line use provide a formal piece of documentation called a manual or man page. For example `man mkdir`

---

**info – Display A Program's Info Entry**

The GNU Project provides an alternative to man pages for their programs, called `info.` Info pages are displayed with a reader program named, appropriately enough, info. Info pages are hyperlinked much like web pages. For example: `info mkdir`

---

**README And Other Program Documentation Files**

Many software packages installed on your system have documentation files residing in the `/usr/share/doc` directory. For example: `less /usr/share/doc/adduser/examples/adduser.local`

---

**

> Briefed from The Linux Command Line book, William E. Shotts, Jr.,
> Second Internet Edition

**

Answer (score 1):

Use the command `man (COMMAND)` in terminal.

For example: if I wanted to learn what `grep` is and how to use it I would run `man grep`.